# Pass function variable to express route

Tags: javascript, node.js

I use this function to check if the user is logged in.

```
function isAuthenticated(req, res, next) {
  const sessionCookie = req.cookies.session || "";

  admin
    .auth()
    .verifySessionCookie(sessionCookie, true /** checkRevoked */)
    .then((user) => {
      //user is logged in
      const id = user.id;
      return next();
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
      //User not logged in
      res.redirect('/login);
    });
};
```

In my routes im calling this function with this code:

```
app.get('/safe', isAuthenticated, function (req, res) {
    res.redirect('safe');
});
```

I want to use the `const id` from the function inside the route, is there way to pass the variable over?

Comment: Did you try '/safe/:id'? Then the value will be at req.params.id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Express exposes a [`locals`](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.locals) property in the response which is an object that is persisted across routes, you you can assign a property to it then access it from your next route:

```js
// ...

.then((user) => {
    // store value to locals
    res.locals.id = user.id;
    return next();
})

// ...

app.get('/safe', isAuthenticated, function (req, res) {
    // you can now use res.locals.id
    res.redirect('safe');
});
```

Comment: `var user = res.locals.id;
ReferenceError: res is not defined`
Its working when I use routes now :) But when I use the variable outside a route I get that error.

Comment: `res.locals` is unique to each request, and therefore can only be referenced in a route.

Comment: How can I export the user.id variable from the function-.then() to use it outside routes? :)

Comment: This seems like a case of the X-Y problem. Why would you ever want to access the user id, something fundamentally tied to the request, outside of the request handlers? It makes no sense that way.

Comment: Outside the routes I have socket.io running, when a user visits the site socket.io checks also if the user is logged in or not. (btw, thank you for your help :))